# Download docker image on non docker computer and transfer it to computer running docker

Tags: windows, docker

Is it possible to download docker image via browser on a computer which doesn't have docker? I want to download following image on a PC which doesn't have docker but has fast connection. Then I want to transfer it to another PC which doesn't have internet but it has docker.
Both are Windows machines.

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-20231212-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save the image to a local file.

[From the Docker documentation,](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) once you've pulled the image onto the PC with a fast connection, run:

```bash
 docker save mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-20231212-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 | gzip > mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-20231212-windowsservercore-ltsc2016.tar.gz
```

This will save the image to a `.tar` file which is then immediately compressed via a pipe to gunzip to make a `.tar.gz` file.

You can then load the image after you've transferred it to your other PC.

```bash
docker load < mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-20231212-windowsservercore-ltsc2016.tar.gz
```

You should now have the image ready to run when you do a `docker image -ls` command.

Comment: "once you've pulled the image onto the PC with a fast connection"; for this and for the `docker save` you need to have docker on the machine. The OP mentioned "a PC which doesn't have docker but has fast connection"